# Access to redirectToRoute in CustomExceptionController

Tags: php, symfony

In /src/AppBundle/Controller/CustomExceptionController.php I have:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CustomExceptionController extends \Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController
{

    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('custom_error'); //not working
    }
}
```

This not working because \Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController not extends class Controller. So how can I use $this->redirectToRoute in this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`redirectToRoute` is part of the `Controller` class like you mentioned. 
All you need to do is create the method yourself.

First you'll need to inject the router into your `CustomExceptionController` (therefore you need to define your custom controller as a service in the DI)

```
services:
my.custom.exception_controller:
    class: CustomExceptionController
    arguments: [ "@twig", "%kernel.debug%", "@router" ]

twig:
    exception_controller: my.custom.exception_controller:showAction
```

Your custom class should look like this:

```
class CustomExceptionController extends \Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController
{
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, $debug, Router $router)
    {
        parent::__construct($twig, $debug);
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {

    }
}
```

After that you can implement the redirectToRoute in the CustomExceptionController just like it's done in the Controller (or just create the RedirectResponse without the helper methods directly)

```
/**
 * Returns a RedirectResponse to the given URL.
 *
 * @param string $url    The URL to redirect to
 * @param int    $status The status code to use for the Response
 *
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
public function redirect($url, $status = 302)
{
    return new RedirectResponse($url, $status);
}

/**
 * Returns a RedirectResponse to the given route with the given parameters.
 *
 * @param string $route      The name of the route
 * @param array  $parameters An array of parameters
 * @param int    $status     The status code to use for the Response
 *
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
protected function redirectToRoute($route, array $parameters = array(), $status = 302)
{
    return $this->redirect($this->router->generateUrl($route, $parameters), $status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way with using UrlGeneratorInterface like

```
 getContainer()->get('router')->generate( 'custom_error', ['key' => 'some val'], 0 );
```

getContainer() - is own funct, see manual [If you need to generate a URL from a service, type-hint the UrlGeneratorInterface service:](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls)

```
// src/Service/SomeService.php

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class SomeService
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate( 'custom_error', [ 'key' => 'some value' ] );

    }
}
```